# What do I need to learn to code an app like Snapchat?

Tags: android, ios

I am new to programming and have been learning for the past month. I am trying to build an app that can record and upload short videos like Snaps to a database. Then the app can access these videos from the database. I am learning Java and Android Studio currently to make the Android version of the app, but later I want to learn the iOS side to make the iOS version of this app.

I would deeply appreciate some guidance on what exactly I need to learn to be able to make this app myself.

Comment: if you want develop app for android and iOS . instead of native go with flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can get started with the Camera API(updated to Camera2 API) and the CameraX API which will help you with photography on Android devices.

[Camera2API described here](https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-camera2-api-from-callbacks-part-1-5d348de65950)

[CameraAPI Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera)

[Video Recording Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics)

[CameraX Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax)

Regarding storage, I suggest that you start with what is provided in the Google Documentation and work your way up from there.

[Storing files on android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files)

The best way to learn is by using the Android Developer Guides as a base and StackOverflow posts to clarify implementation problems and troubleshooting.

Cheers!